# Print data table with jsf with lanscap

Tags: java, css, jsf, jsf-2

I have datatable with 30 column , but when printing it was 50% only printed and 50% missing so i want to print it with landscape mode to take all A4 Space .

so i don't know which code CSS use and how to implement it in HTML page with prime faces or jsf java .

**xhtml code:**

```
<h:commandButton value="طباعة التقرير" type="button"
        icon="ui-icon-print">
        <p:printer target="hesham" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this: [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17459)

It looks like the same problem you are having !